# unity & kinect, saving animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, kinect, clip

I am working on a project/game in which a physical therapist can use a Kinect to record an exercise,  and it should be played back with an avatar. I have it working with animation clips, but I would like to store each exercise for later use. Is there a way I can save it to a file?

Sorry if I am not specific enough, I am very new to unity and programming in general. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to save an animation clip instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for Serialization.  Serialization allows you to save the state of any C# object to an XML file, and reload the object from the XML file later.

**Further Reading**
[How to Write Object Data to an XML File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172873.aspx)
[How to Read Object Data from an XML File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172872.aspx)